# Examine the convergence of a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ which is given by $a_{1}=a>0,a_{2}=b>0, a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}a_{n}},n\ge 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I used inequality between arithmetic and geometric means to show that a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is bounded:
$$a_{n+2}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}a_{n}}\le \frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n}}{2}$$

Solving this, I get quadratic inequality
$$a^2_{n+1}-2a_{n+1}a_{n}+a^2_{n}\ge 0$$

which gets me to $$0\le a_{n}\le 1$$
thus, sequence is bounded.

I get that sequence is not monotonic, because
$$a_{n}\le a_{n+2} \le {a_{n+1}}$$
or
$$a_{n+1}\le a_{n+2} \le {a_{n}}$$

Is this right?

Comment: hi, the quadratic inequality is always true, which could not give you the bound. In fact, you could use the math induction to show the boundedness of the sequence.

Comment: @Chival  Can you show the induction steps?

Comment: let $M = a\vee b$, then $a_1, a_2\leq M$. Suppose $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ is bounded by $M$, then $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_{n-1}\times a_n} \leq M$. This implies by induction that $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence bounded by $M$. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_n=\log a_n$. Then the sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ satisfies the recursive relation:
$$
c_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}c_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}c_{n}, \quad c_1=\log a,\,\,c_2=\log b.
$$
Then we have
$$
c_{n+2}-c_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{2}\big(c_{n+1}-c_{n})=\cdots=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(c_2-c_1). \tag{1}
$$
Also
$$
c_{n+2}+\frac{1}{2}c_{n+1}=c_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}c_{n}=\cdots=c_{2}+\frac{1}{2}c_{1}.
\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain
$$
c_{n+2}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2c_2+c_1+\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}(c_2-c_1)\right)
$$
and hence
$$
a_n=a^{1/3}b^{2/3}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{(-1)^n/2^{n-2}}\to a^{1/3}b^{2/3},
$$
since $c^{1/2^n}\to 1$, for every $c>0$.

Note. Proving convergence, without finding the limit, is simpler, as $\{a_{2n+1}\}$ is increasing, $\{a_{2n}\}$ is decreasing, and $a_{2n+2}/a_{2n+1}=\sqrt{a_{2n}/a_{2n-1}}=(a_2/a_1)^{1/2^n}\to 1$.

Comment: I don't understand how did you get $a_n=a^{1/3}b^{2/3}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{(-1)^n/2^{n-2}}\to a^{1/3}b^{2/3}$. Everything else is clear.

Comment: @displayerror See the last line of my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Assume WLOG $a<b$.
- Now show that the even subsequence $\{a_{2n}\}$ and the odd subsequence $\{a_{2n-1}\}$ are individually monotonic.
- Show that all the terms of one of these subsequences are greater than all the terms of the other subsequence.
- So you have got bounded monotonic even subsequence and bounded monotonic odd subsequence. One of them is increasing and the other is decreasing. Show that the limits of these two subsequences are equal.
- Conclude that this information is sufficient to show that the whole sequence converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut: assume that a real sequence is given by some values of $c_1,c_2$ and the recurrence relation $c_{n+2}=\frac{c_n+c_{n+1}}{2}$. Then it is convergent since:
$$ \left|c_{n+1}-c_n\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|c_{n}-c_{n-1}\right| \tag{1}$$
and it converges to $\frac{c_1+2c_2}{3}$ since:
$$ c_{n}+2 c_{n+1} = c_{n+1}+2 c_{n+2}.\tag{2} $$
By setting $c_n=\log a_n$, it follows that:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = \sqrt[3]{a_1 a_2^2}.\tag{3}$$